# Parent class instance variable getting overridden when executing from the parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = "A"

    def create(self):
        print(f"Model in class {self.model}")


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = "B"

    def save(self):
        super().create()
        print(f"Model in class Bar {self.model}")


bar = Bar()
bar.save()
```

Output:

> Model in class Foo B
>
> Model in class Bar B

Why is the variable `model` in class `Foo` getting overridden when it is in the parent class. Is this what should really happen? I want to make it the print `A` when it is executing from the parent class. What's going wrong here in the code?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the variable model in class Foo getting overridden when it is
> in the parent class.

Because that `self` parameter in the `create()` method is bound to the instance of the `Bar`. So it first checks the `bar`'s dictionary and yes there is a `model` attribute which has the value of `"B"`. Insert a simple print statement to check that:

```py
    def create(self):
        print(self)
        print(f'Model in class {self.model}')
```

And why its value is `"B"` and not `"A"`? Because the order of calling `super().__init__()` and `self.model = 'B'` matters. If you change the order it has the value of `"A"`. Again add a simple print statement between these two and you'll see it prints "`A`":

```py
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.model)
        self.model = 'B'
```

Comment: If i change the order like you said it will print A in both function that's not what i wanted i want to **creat** to print A and **save** to print B, if i implement this same code in java it will do like i said

Comment: @ABHIJITHEA It's not possible. As I said, you're calling the method `.create()` in `.save()` "*from*" the instance of `Bar`, not `Foo`. That `super().create()` is a shortcut to say `super(Bar, self).create()`. You see that `self` ? It's the bound instance to the method. It's your `bar` instance. If you store or retrieve something from it, you store/retrieve from its instance dictionary.

Comment: Is there any way i could achieve that, like i said it  is possible in java do you know any way in python like that

Comment: @ABHIJITHEA No it's not possible. Since I don't speak java, I don't know what are you talking about but `create` is a method that is inherited from `Foo` class. Its `self` parameter is your `bar` which is an instance of `Bar` not `Foo`, so how do you expect that `self.model` which is initialized for `bar` to be `"B"`, be `"A"`? How is that even possible? Even that `self.model = 'A'` in `Foo`'s initializer, stores the `'A'` in the instance dictionary of `bar`, why? Because that `self` is also `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. Everything works as expected.
This line executes initializer of Class `Bar` and from this moment `bar.model` is pointing to string `B`

```py
bar=Bar()
```

When you call the parent class method it is indeed executed (what you can observe by the output of print), but this doesn't change the value of attribute `model` of object `bar`.

**Disclaimer!**

Since you are making edits to the question this answer will soon make no sense neither...
If you call `super().create()` directly below the`super().__init__()` call and BEFORE the assignment to `self.model` you can see the desired behaviour.

Comment: Then how can i print 'A' inside the create, i want to print respective models of the classes